# A Java Card Game with Multiple Decks

Tags: java

I am in need of help in creating a java card game that:

- Asks a user how many Decks they want to play with
- Asks a user how many random Cards to draw from each deck (n)
- Deals the (n) Cards drawn from each Deck each time the user presses
  enter
- Notifies the user if there are no more cards left in the deck
- Asks the user if they want to play again
- If the user wants to play again, everything must be reset

So far, I can only get my program to draw cards from one deck, one time. I need to draw n cards from n decks over and over until there are no more cards left, then the program needs to reset.

I have made multiple classes for this program:

Card Class:

```
public class Card{
    private int rank, suit;

    private static String[] suits = { "hearts", "spades", "diamonds", "clubs" };
    private static String[] ranks  = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };


    Card(int suit, int rank)
    {
        this.rank=rank;
        this.suit=suit;
    }

    public @Override String toString()
    {
          return ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit];
    }

    public int getRank() {
         return rank;
    }

    public int getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }
}
```

Deck Class:

```
public class Deck {
    private ArrayList<Card> cards;
     Deck()
    {
        cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
        int index_1, index_2;
        Random generator = new Random();
        Card temp;

        for (int a=0; a<=3; a++)
        {
            for (int b=0; b<=12; b++)
             {
               cards.add( new Card(a,b) );
             }
        }


        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            index_1 = generator.nextInt( cards.size() - 1 );
            index_2 = generator.nextInt( cards.size() - 1 );

            temp = (Card) cards.get( index_2 );
            cards.set( index_2 , cards.get( index_1 ) );
            cards.set( index_1, temp );
        }
    }

    public Card drawFromDeck(Scanner console)
    {      
        return cards.remove(0);
    }

    public int getTotalCards()
    {
        return cards.size();
    }

    public int getNumberOfDecks(Scanner console){
        int tempNumDecks = 0;
        boolean isOk = false;

        System.out.println("How many decks would you like to use?");

        do{
            try{
                String userInput = console.nextLine();
                tempNumDecks = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

                if(tempNumDecks <= 0) {
                    System.out.println ("Invalid input. Enter a number > 0");
                    isOk = false;
                }//end if
                else{
                    isOk = true;
                }//end else
            }//end try
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Enter an integer greater than 0:");
            }//end catch
        }while(isOk == false);
        return tempNumDecks;
    }//end getNumberOfDecks()

    public int getNumberOfCards(Scanner console){
        int tempNumCards = 0;
        boolean isOk = false;

        System.out.println("How many cards would you like to deal?");

        do{
            try{
                String userInput = console.nextLine();
                tempNumCards = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

                if(tempNumCards <= 0) {
                    System.out.println ("Invalid input. Enter a number > 0");
                    isOk = false;
                }//end if
                else{
                    isOk = true;
                }//end else
            }//end try
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Enter an integer greater than 0:");
            }//end catch
        }while(isOk == false);
        return tempNumCards;
    }//end getNumberOfCards()
}
```

CardDealer Class:

```
public class CardDealer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Shuffle!");

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        Card card;
        int decks = deck.getNumberOfDecks(console);
        int cards = deck.getNumberOfCards(console);

        while(deck.getTotalCards() != (52-cards)){
            card = deck.drawFromDeck(console);
            System.out.println( card.toString() );

        }
    }   
}
```

Code output:

```
Welcome to Shuffle!
How Many decks would you like to use? (USER INPUT: 4) <---This is unused
How many cards would you like to deal? (USER INPUT: 5) <---This actually works
7 of diamonds
3 of diamonds
Queen of spades
8 of hearts
Jack of spades
```

So, I'm getting multiple cards, but not multiple decks. Please help me figure this out, I am very new to java and StackOverflow in general.

Let me know if I can provide any other information (this is my first post :x)

Thank you.

EDIT:: I have created an arrayList that holds a number of decks decided by the user. However, I am having trouble drawing cards from multiple decks. This only draws one set of cards from one of the decks.

```
package javacards;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CardDealer {

    private static ArrayList<Deck> decks;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Shuffle!");

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        Deck deck = new Deck();
        int numdecks = deck.getNumberOfDecks(console);
        decks = new ArrayList<Deck>();

        Card card;
        int cards = deck.getNumberOfCards(console);

        for (int a=0; a < numdecks; a++){

            decks.add( a , new Deck() );

        }


        while(deck.getTotalCards() != (52-cards)){
            card = deck.drawFromDeck(console);
            System.out.println( card.toString() );


        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I suggest using an `ArrayList` and a loop to create the multiple decks.

Comment: Basically my question is how do i create multiple decks and draw the user-decided number of cards from each deck. I also need to know how to continue to draw from the deck(s) until their corresponding array lists are empty.

Answer (score 0):

1. To use multiple decks, create an `ArrayList<Deck>`. This is very similar to the `ArrayList<Card>` which you have already.
2. To continue until a deck is empty, add a `isEmpty()` method to your `Deck` class and use a `while` loop.

Comment: Does it matter which class i put the arraylist<decks> in? im gonna try and put it in the cardDealer class.